# Find the smallest value in row and store it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+--+
| ID | Test1 | Test2 | Test3 |  |
+----+-------+-------+-------+--+
| 1  | 2     | 3     | 4     |  |
+----+-------+-------+-------+--+
| 2  | 2     | 3     | 1     |  |
+----+-------+-------+-------+--+
| 3  | 1     | 5     | 7     |  |
+----+-------+-------+-------+--+
```

I'd like to find the smallest value from `Test1, Test2, Test3` for each row.

The next table will store only the smallest value.

How can I create this table?

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+--+
| ID | Test1 | Test2 | Test3 |  |
+----+-------+-------+-------+--+
| 1  | 2     | 0     | 0     |  |
+----+-------+-------+-------+--+
| 2  | 0     | 0     | 1     |  |
+----+-------+-------+-------+--+
| 3  | 1     | 0     | 0     |  |
+----+-------+-------+-------+--+
```

I use `pandas` module and `DataFrame`.

I know how to find the smallest value in `Test1, Test2, Test3`, but I don't know how to find the name of the column then.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

We can get the `min` value over each row `axis=1`. Then we check on each row which value is equal to this  with `.eq(axis=0)`. Then we use `where` to convert all other values to `0`:

```
df = df.set_index('ID')
mask = df.eq(df.min(axis=1), axis=0)
df.where(mask, other=0).reset_index()
```

```
   ID  Test1  Test2  Test3
0   1      2      0      0
1   2      0      0      1
2   3      1      0      0
```